# Hypernym for "Denial"?

Tags: hypernyms

Dictionary defines *denial* in a few senses, the ones I'm interested in are:

> - refusal to believe a doctrine, theory, or the like.
> - disbelief in the existence or reality of a thing.
> - refusal to recognize or acknowledge.

In particular, I mean unreasonable disbelief in reality of a thing which is definitely, objectively real.

Now, I want to say:

> Denial is a horrible [what?]

trait of character? (not really, it's specific, not encompassing whole personality) vice? (same) belief? idea? (no, it's a property of a belief or idea...)

How would you classify it?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you mean by "hypernym" here. Denial and, for example, acceptance, are both covered by the more general term "reaction". But you seem to be looking for a hypernym to cover only and all reactions involving **rejection** of a generally-accepted truth. I'm not convinced "hypernym" is appropriate in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Quite possible that I misused that word here. If you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears.

Comment: It's not so much the *word* "hypernym" that I'm questioning - it's the very idea that since there are many different ways someone can "reject a generally-accepted truth", and many ways to describe such reactions, there might be (ought to be?) a "hypernym" covering all of them. I could be wrong, but I think all you'll get is subjective answers reflecting people's attitudes to whatever they associate with "unorthodox rejection".

Comment: You really mean 'being in denial' (is horrible), not 'denial' itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denial is a horrible *state of mind* or a horrible *defence mechanism* or a horrible *mental/emotional* condition.

Comment: +1 for state of mind - also, denial is sometimes useful, at least temporarily

Comment: +1 for "defense mechanism" which denial is undeniably a case of. This directly answers OP's question.

Answer (score 5):

Denial can be many things, including an *attitude* or *orientation towards life* or *orientation towards reality.*

Answer (score 2):

The type of denial you are referencing seems to fit under the characterization of *intentional obliviousness*.  The word *oblivious* is [defined](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oblivious?view=uk) as

> not aware of or concerned about what is happening around one:

While obliviousness can sometimes be seem as accidental or inadvertent, I would characterize *deliberate* obliviousness as a *[mindset](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mindset?q=mindset)*

> the established set of attitudes held by someone:
>   *the region seems stuck in a medieval mindset*

Comment: +1 for _mindset_; I think that's my favorite out of everything suggested so far.

Answer (score 2):

You might say, “Denial is a horrible *stance*.”

Consider NOAD's definition of the word:

> **stance** - the attitude of a person or organization toward something; a standpoint

My Mac's on-board thesaurus offers these synonyms:

> attitude, stand, point of view, viewpoint, opinion, way of thinking, outlook, standpoint, position, angle, perspective, approach, line, policy.

Answer (score 2):

And, of course, there is simply:

> *Denial* is a horrible ***thing***.

Answer (score 1):

How about *response*?

Going beyond the remit of your question, I suggest:

> Denialism is an ugly response.

I used *denialism* rather than *denial* because I think it better fits what you are trying to express.  Wikipedia defines denialism as *choosing to deny reality as a way to avoid an uncomfortable truth*.  And *ugly* implies that it reflects poorly on the denier which, again, more closely matches what I think you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

A hypernym for *denial* in this case would be [***apology***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apology_%28Plato%29) in its most formal sense.

I think you would be correct in saying, "Denial is a horrible apology for ..."

Those "in denial" of something in this sense are often called *apologists*, but apology is broader than denial.

Answer (score 0):

"Indulgence" or if you are willing to use two words, it is more vivid and judgemental sounding to call it a "self indulgence". Finally, I also like to think of denial of, say, a historical event, as a "deficiency". Denial is a horrible deficiency in an educated person.